# IF-Statement Compile Error

Tags: vba, excel

I got the compile error message - `End If without If Block`. Can anyone tell what is wrong with my code:

```
Sub Find()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

For i = 2 To 107
For j = 4 To 6
    For k = 2 To 573
    If InStr(Sheet2.Cells(k, 7), Sheet1.Cells(i, j)) <> 0 Then Sheet2.Cells(k, 12) =         Sheet2.Cells(k, 9)
    End If
    Next k
Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Two options for you: 1) remove `End If`, or 2) write `Sheet2.Cells(k, 12) = Sheet2.Cells(k, 9)` in new line

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use End If for inline If statements. Just remove it and you'll be ok, or move the bit after then to the next line.

You need to use End If when you have a multi-line if statement

Comment: Thank you, and when do i need to use end if?

Comment: oh and also, i dont understatnd why before I changed the operator from "<>" to ">", my then statement execute anyways, after i changed to ">", it does not execute, assuming "InStr(Sheet2.Cells(k, 7), Sheet1.Cells(i, j))" return to false

Comment: You need to use End If when you have a multiline if statement Like 
    If bla = 1 Then
       dosomething()
    End If

Your code should also work fine with >, but it really does the same thing in your case.

Comment: thanks for your answer, and I figured out why the return is always true, because I had some blank cells as input for search